# Using stringstream to read integers and add them up

Tags: c++, stdout, stdin, stringstream

I am trying to use string stream to output the sum of integers in each line of standard input using string stream. This is what I have so far

```
void sumvec(vector<int> v) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
           total += v[i];
    }
    cout << total << endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::string line;
    std::stringstream sstream(line); 
    int i;
    while (getline(std::cin, line)){
        while (sstream >> i) { 
            v.push_back(i); 
        }
        sumvec(v);
    }

}
```

I want each line to have its own sum. But when I do this nothing is being returned to output. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `std::stringstream sstream(line);` constructs a string stream with the current contents of `line`. It doesn't create some sort of link between the string stream and `line` such that if you write to `line` the string stream will be updated automatically. Declare variables only when you need them so that you'll have less mistakes like this. `sstream` should be inside the first while loop.

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger. Bugs like this are pretty obvious when you step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: `std::string line; while (getline(std::cin, line)) { std::stringstream sstream(line); while (sstream >> i) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

`sstream` is empty when you use it in the second `while`: `while (sstream >> i)`. That's because you initialized it with an empty `std::string line;`. You can move it inside the first while loop:

```
while (getline(std::cin, line)){
    std::stringstream sstream(line);
```

This will fix your code.

Some suggestions to improve your code:

Additionally, always initialize your variables, so `int i` should be `int i = 0;` or `int i{};`.

It seems you are just reading from the stdin into `line` and then converting it into an `int`. You can use `std::stoi()` instead of a `stringstream` which might be sufficient in this case.

`sumvec` contains a raw loop to add all the elements of a `vector`. You can instead use [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) to do that. Example:

```
int total = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
cout << total << endl;
```

If you still want to use `sumvec`, make sure you pass the vector by reference instead. This will avoid a copy, resulting in better performance  and you will have a gurantee that `v` will not change in this function. It also makes it clear for the reader what this function does.

```
void sumvec(const vector<int>& v) {
```

Additionally, in your loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
```

You are comparing `size_t` with `int`. `size_t` is of `unsigned` while `int` is not. Avoid that as much as possible. Instead use `size_t`:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
```